# Change a value inside an existing JSON file

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the value of `numberOfEvents` and `recordingTime` inside a JSON file. Unfortunately it does not work.

This is what I got as the error:

**EDIT**: Still the same error if I change `"numberOfEvents":0,` to `"numberOfEvents":"0",`. `Class 'String' has no instance method 'add'.`

```
E/flutter (25057): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'add'.
E/flutter (25057): Receiver: 0
E/flutter (25057): Tried calling: add("0")
E/flutter (25057): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
```

What is the best way to change the value of a key inside a JSON that exists?

```json
{
"version":"1.0.0",
"numberOfEvents":0,
"recordingTime":"00:00:00",
"data":[{
       "data1": "data"
       ]}
}
```

```dart
  static writeRecording(String numberOfEvents, String recordingtime) async {
    print("Writing to file the last info");
    final path = await _localPath;

    File file = File(path + filename2);
    var jsonObject = json.decode(file.readAsStringSync());


    jsonObject['numberOfEvents'].add(numberOfEvents);
    jsonObject['recordingTime'].add(recordingtime);
    file.writeAsString(json.encode(jsonObject), mode: FileMode.write);
  }
```

Comment: you can do jsonObject['numberOfEvents']=123; jsonObject['recordingTime']="123"

Comment: in your JSON,  the field "numberOfEvents" is expected to be of type int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is because you're trying to use the add() method on an int object (numberOfEvents) and a String object (recordingTime). However, add() is meant for adding elements to a List, not for modifying the values of properties in a JSON object.

Try this

```
static writeRecording(String numberOfEvents, String recordingTime) async 
 {
     print("Writing to file the last info");
     final path = await _localPath;

     File file = File(path + filename2);
     var jsonObject = json.decode(file.readAsStringSync());

     jsonObject['numberOfEvents'] = numberOfEvents;
     jsonObject['recordingTime'] = recordingTime;

     file.writeAsString(json.encode(jsonObject), mode: FileMode.write);
 }
```